# Correcting NaN values/loss for ANN in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nan

I am running a churn model using tensorflow and running into a NaN loss. Reading around, I found that I probably had some NaN values in my data as was confirmed by `print(np.any(np.isnan(X_test)))`.

I tried using

```py
def standardize(train, test):
    mean = np.mean(train, axis=0)
    std = np.std(train, axis=0)+0.000001
    X_train = (train - mean) / std
    X_test = (test - mean) /std
    return X_train, X_test
```

But still coming up with NaN values.

Here's the full code if it helps:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = pd.read_excel('CHURN DATA.xlsx')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 2:45].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 45].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = le.fit_transform(X[:,1])

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[0])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 43, activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 43, activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
ann.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
ann.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 256, epochs = 50)
```

Comment: After `dataset = pd.read_excel('CHURN DATA.xlsx')` add `dataset = dataset.dropna()`

Comment: This worked, but it dropped 80% of the data. As suggested below im working with negative values in some inputs (overdrawn checking account balances etc)

Comment: It’s dropping 80% of the data because the dropna function will remove the entire row once it finds nan even if it is only one. Use fillna instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent replaced the `nan` values. And it’s likely that you have some `inf` and `-inf` values also in your data. You can replace both of them with `0`

For dataframe

```
X.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
X = X.fillna(0)
```

or if your data is in a numpy array

```
X[np.isnan(X)] = 0

X[X == np.inf] = 0 
X[X == -np.inf] = 0
```

Comment: I am working with negative values in some inputs (overdrawn checking account balances etc). When I try this I get the following error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I assumed your data is in a dataframe, but apparently the data is in a numpy array. So you can either convert your data to dataframe and use the solution above, or use this: `X[X == np.inf] = 0  X[X == -np.inf] = 0`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I ran ` X[X == np.inf] = 0  X[X == -np.inf] = 0`after encoding my categorical variables but still getting print(np.any(np.isnan(X_test))) = True after, and still encountering nan loss

Comment: Run this too `X[np.isnan(X)] = 0`. Also where are you placing this replace method in your code?

Comment: Worked! I used ` X.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
X = X.fillna(0) ` for the whole dataset which is in dataframe as  `dataset.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
dataset = dataset.fillna(0) ` . Model ran smoothly ended up with .99 accuracy. Thanks!!