# Input contains nfinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logistic-regression

I have taken a dataset, analysed ,  wrangled it and now while coming to training the model the error shown is this.

```
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I have used functions like

```
np.any(np.isnan(titanic_data))  #outputs true

np.all(np.isfinite(titanic_data)) # outputs false

np.isfinite(titanic_data.all()) #true for everthing, dtype is bool.
```

this is the wrangled

[image: dataset[final_dataset.png]]

the error shown for the following code is

```
logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
predections = logmodel.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
classification_report(y_test,predictions)
```

> error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: If your `titanic_data` is a type `DataFrame`, then you could use the code: `df = df.dropna(axis=0)`. df refers to the data_frame

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63203653/1836069